# Sublime text compile multiple files in windows

Tags: c, gcc

I can use command line to compile multiple .c files

```
eg: gcc ./list.c ./main.c -o ./main.
```

BUT How can I use sublime text to compile multiple .c files, such as I have a

```
list.h, list.c, main.c
```

PS:I can compile a simple .c file on sublime.

Comment: Create a makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be to use `Makefile` which you can run with GCC. I suppose you have installed `make` command. If not, install it with mingw.

In your make file specify list of files you want to compile and just run `make` from sublime command line.